# Difference between macro and quantifier in Z3

Tags: z3

I would like to know what is the difference between following 2 statements -

**Statement 1**

```
(define-fun max_integ ((x Int) (y Int)) Int 
  (ite (< x y) y x))
```

**Statement 2**

```
(declare-fun max_integ ((Int)(Int)) Int)
(assert (forall ((x Int) (y Int)) (= (max_integ x y) (if (< x y) y x))))
```

I observed that when I use Statement1, my z3 constraints give me a result in 0.03 seconds. Whereas when I used Statement2, it does not finish in 2 minutes and I terminate the solver.
I would like also to know how achieve it using C-API.

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Statement 1 is a macro. Z3 will replace every occurrence of `max_integ` with the `ite` expression. It does that during parsing time. In the second statement, by default, Z3 will not  eliminate `max_integ`, and to be able to return `sat` it has to build an interpretation for the uninterpreted symbol `max_integ` that will satisfy the quantifier for all `x` and `y`. 
Z3 has an option called `:macro-finder`, it will detect quantifiers that are essentially encoding macros, and will eliminate them. Here is an example (also available online [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/Ho5N)):

```
(set-option :macro-finder true)
(declare-fun max_integ ((Int)(Int)) Int)
(assert (forall ((x Int) (y Int)) (= (max_integ x y) (if (< x y) y x))))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

That being said, we can easily simulate macros in a programmatic API by writing a function that given Z3 expressions return a new Z3 expression. Here in an example using the Python API (also available online [here](http://rise4fun.com/z3py)):

```
def max(a, b):
   # The function If builds a Z3 if-then-else expression
   return If(a >= b, a, b)

x, y = Ints('x y')
solve(x == max(x, y), y == max(x, y), x > 0)
```

Yet another option is to use the C API: `Z3_substitute_vars`. The idea is to an expression containing free variables. Free variables are created using the API `Z3_mk_bound`. Each variable represents an argument. Then, we use `Z3_substitute_vars` to replace the variables with other expressions.

Comment: is it possible for you to include a small example for the same quantifier using `Z3_substitute_vars`?

Comment: The file `examples/c/test_capi.c` has an example: function `substitute_vars_example()`. Here is a link to this file: http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/4c353ec7204a6a16f9b87eb1bbae694db40076cb#examples/c/test_capi.c