# (define-fun ...) in SMT solvers

Tags: z3, smt

How do SMT solvers (Z3 in particular) use functions defined using (define-fun ...)?  Are these function definitions expanded right way (as macros) or lazily (as needed with certain arguments)?

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/15768713/936310, it'll be expanded immediately; during parse time.

However, that answer dates back to 2013; so it's conceivable things have changed in the meantime. The best place to ask these sorts of questions is the z3 discussion forum: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/discussions