# How to compile Z3 (Skolem) functions

Tags: z3

I am using a tool that returns (Skolem) functions such as:

```
(define-fun y ((x1 Int)(x2 Int)) Int
    (ite (<= (+ x1 (- x2)) 0) x2 x1))
```

Now, I would like to use such functions in some part of a program. How can I use them? Is there a way they can compiled (i.e., compile Z3) and used as black-box input-output functions? Maybe to parse them back into Z3-Py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is doable, but not in a straightforward way. The main function you are looking for is `parse_smt2_string`. Unfortunately, it only deals with declarations and assertions. In particular it doesn't handle definitions (also known as macros).

So, provided you are willing to tweak your string-definition for the function slightly, you can do:

```py
from z3 import *

s = Then('macro-finder', 'smt').solver()

s.add(parse_smt2_string(
"""
(declare-fun y (Int Int) Int)
(assert (forall ((x1 Int) (x2 Int))
           (= (y x1 x2)
              (ite (<= (+ x1 (- x2)) 0) x2 x1))))
"""
))
```

Note that we created a specific solver that triggers the macro-finder tactic first. Without this, the quantification will be too hard to deal with for z3. We also tweaked the definition of your `y` into a `declare-fun` and into a quantified assertion. This is essential to get `parse_smt2_string` work.

How do you use this function in z3-py then? Well, simply declare it and use it like you'd any other function:

```py
y = Function('y', IntSort(), IntSort(), IntSort())
r = Int ('r')
s.add(r == y(5, 6))

print(s.check())
m = s.model()
print(m[r])
```

Together with the above segment, this prints:

```py
sat
6
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the response. Okey, I see you "do not want" a quantifier alternation, so manipulate the formula so that it only contains "forall". However, I do not understand how using `y = x1` and `x2` does the trick. In any case, I would like to get this process automatic, is there a way? I mean, does this suggest a general way of solving the problem: concretely, is `y` always made assertion `=` to the rest of the forall inputs?

Comment: For instance,  if the function is `define-fun y y ((x1 Int)(x2 Int)(x3 Int)(x4 Int)) Int) (phi)` does `(declare-fun y ...
(assert (forall ...
           (= (y x1 x2 x3 x4)
              phi ` do the trick? Thanks again for the detailed response.

Comment: Yes; you simply turn into one assert with forall's of all arguments; nothing else. This is what the `macro-finder` tactic does: It recognizes such definitions and uses them as a rewrite, instead of going through expensive quantifier reasoning. To be honest, I'm not sure why z3 doesn't support `define-fun`'s in `parse_smt_string`. I suspect it's for historical reasons, might be good to check with them.

Comment: Forgive my lack of understanding, but what exactly is a "macro" and why is it less expensive to use them versus reasoning with quantifiers. I mean, I understand that reasoning with quantifiers is expensive, what I don't understand is what is the catch here. I've looked at other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758699/difference-between-macro-and-quantifier-in-z3 and here de Moura answers: "Z3 has an option called :macro-finder, it will detect quantifiers that are essentially encoding macros, and will eliminate them". But I just don't understand the basics: what are macros?

Comment: A macro is essentially a (non-recursive) definition. It's called a macro, because whenever you see it, you can substitute the right-hand side while preserving the semantics exactly. Think of it like unfolding the body of a function. Thus, the quantification all goes to the top-level, which is much easier to deal with.